# Mapping POST data to objects via Stripes

Tags: java, forms, jsp, stripes

I've been googling like a madman trying to figure this out.

So I typically see JSP pages with form values with names like this:

```
<input name="${object.member}" type="text" />
```

Which maps to the 'object' variable on the ActionBean.  In some code that I'm looking at it gets even more in depth

```
${object.memberMap[key].member}
```

So presumably, when you submit a form, you can have it auto map these values to Java objects, right?  However, this is not what I'm seeing, but I am fairly certain that other code takes advantage

My question is: is there a way to manually trigger this kind of auto-mapping of POST data from a form to object values on an ActionBean?

Comment: This code is typically seen when using a Java EE MVC framework such as [JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info), [Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-mvc/info), [Struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/struts2/info), etc. Are you using any one of them? If not, you'd have to choose and use one. This question is then not constructive enough for SO.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Stripes which is similar to Struts, I believe.

Comment: You should then retag the question as such.

Comment: Thanks for that... I guess part of the problem was that I didn't know the right question to ask!

Comment: The input should really look like `<input name=object.member>` - you don't want the *value* of that property, you want to use the name so that it will be bound by Stripes when you post the form.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map a variable of action Class to jsp variable, you need to create getter and setter methods of the object and use `<s:text>` instead of `<input type="text">` For example

```
In Jsp
<s:text name="user.email"></s:text>

In java class

private User user;
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

And inside User class

private String email;
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```